# Can Atom Editor snippets be composed for expansion

Tags: atom-editor, code-snippets

Does there exist some inclusion mechanism whereby snippet expansion results in the expansion of other snippets?

For example, something along the lines of:

```
'Part 1' : 
  'prefix': 'part1'
  'body' : 'part 1 stuff'

'Part 2' : 
  'prefix': 'part2'
  'body' : 'part 2 stuff'

'Composer' : 
  'prefix': 'compose'
  'body' : """
    composers stuff
    ${include: part1}
    ${include: part2}
  """
  'description' :  'expands to self and parts 1 and 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Atom snippets aren't that fancy. But as a workaround, you could use the names of the other snippets to indicate further expansions:

```
  'Part 1':
    'prefix': 'part1'
    'body': 'part 1 stuff'
  'Part 2':
    'prefix': 'part2'
    'body': 'part 2 stuff'
  'Composer':
    'prefix': 'compose'
    'description': 'expands to self and snippet names for parts 1 and 2'
    'body': """
    composers stuff
    part1$1
    part2$2
    """
```

1. Type `compose` then <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

   ```
   composers stuff
   part1|
   part2
   ```

   (pipe indicates cursor)
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again:

   ```
   composers stuff
   part 1 stuff|
   part2
   ```
3. Go to the end of `part2`, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again:

   ```
   composers stuff
   part 1 stuff
   part 2 stuff|
   ```

   (You need to manually go to the end because once you expand the `part1` snippet, the tab stops in the `compose` snippet go away. But I specified both tab stops in the `compose` snippet to indicate that they're sub-snippets and so that you can skip expanding `part1` if needed. This is especially doable if you set another keybind for `snippets:next-tab-stop` instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>; the use of the same key always bothered me personally anyway.)